# Freeing a wstring after wcsncpy causes heap corruption

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to get some legacy code to cooperate, and the last free statement in this truncated code snippet will fail with a debug assertion (Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData))

```
const wchar_t* sourceMessage = L"testMessage";
const auto sizeOfSourceMessage = sizeof(wchar_t) * (wcsnlen(sourceMessage, 1000) + 1);

// Copy once and free
wchar_t* destination = static_cast<wchar_t*>(malloc(sizeOfSourceMessage));
const auto ret = wcsncpy_s(destination, sizeOfSourceMessage, sourceMessage, sizeOfSourceMessage);
free(destination);
```

Commenting out the second-to-last line with the string copy will make the free operation work.  The return value for the copy is 0, though.

Why does the copy apparently mess up my heap?

(Running on Visual C++ under VS2013 on a Windows 10 PC)

Edit:
So I listened to Some Programmer Dude and this works a lot better:

```
        const wchar_t* sourceMessage = L"testMessage";
        const auto sizeOfSourceMessageInBytes = sizeof(wchar_t) * (wcsnlen(sourceMessage, 1000) + 1);
        const auto sizeOfSourceMessageInWChars = wcsnlen(sourceMessage, 1000);

        // Copy once and free
        wchar_t* destination = static_cast<wchar_t*>(malloc(sizeOfSourceMessageInBytes));
        const auto ret = wcsncpy_s(destination, sizeOfSourceMessageInWChars, sourceMessage, _TRUNCATE);
        free(destination);
```

Comment: In `wcsncpy_s`, should not the size (i.e. `sizeOfSourceMessage`) be the number of *character* to copy? You're passing the size of the buffer in *bytes*.

Comment: BTW, what exactly are you doing?  Why not use a `std::wstring` to abstract away the memory management?

Comment: BTW, appreciate the suggestions to use more abstract concepts than free and malloc, however I'd really like to understand why the legacy code didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You wipe tail of allocated space using sizes in bytes, when character counts are needed. You are allocating 24 bytes of memory then say to `wcsncpy_s`, take this buffer, you could fit 24 wchar_t here, for which 48 bytes are needed (assuming Visual C++ meaning of wchar_t).

**`wcsncpy_s` in debug build, before making copy, fills whole destination buffer with 0xfd bytes for detecting bugs, so it is trashing 24 bytes after allocated buffer.**

I would strongly suggest to use C++ allocation operators `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc`, `free`.

```
const wchar_t* sourceMessage = L"testMessage";
const int sizeOfSourceMessage = wcsnlen(sourceMessage, 1000);

// Copy once and free
wchar_t* destination = new wchar_t[ sizeOfSourceMessage + 1 ];
const auto ret = wcsncpy_s( destination, sizeOfSourceMessage + 1, sourceMessage, sizeOfSourceMessage );
delete[] destination;
```

Or use `wstring`.